# my r program for counting missing data in files

Tags: r

I have created my program for counting the missing data in a file with more than 10,000 rows (I have 1700 files like this). At the end the warning message says:
:"Error in if ((b[i, 5] == NA) && (b[i, 1] > 1980)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

The code is written below:

```
rm(list=ls())
setwd("C:\\Users\\.......")
a <- list.files();
n=0;
j=1;
mat <- matrix(data=NA,nrow=20000,ncol=8);
colnames(mat)<-c("Station","S.Year","S.Month","S.Day","E.Year","E.Month","E.Day","Count");
d<-matrix(data=NA,nrow=3,ncol=1);
for( k in 1:length(a) )
{
    b <- as.matrix(read.table(a[k],skip=7,header=F));
    t<-gsub(".txt","",a[k])

    for(i in 1:(length(b[,1])-1))

        {                     
        if((b[i,5]==NA)&&(b[i,1]>1980))
             {n=n+1;

            if(n==1)
            {d[1,1]=b[i,1]
            d[2,1]=b[i,2]
            d[3,1]=b[i,3]}

        if((b[i+1,5]!=NA)||(i==(length(b[,1])-1)))
            { if(n>10)
             {mat[j,1]=t;
              mat[j,2]=d[1,1]
              mat[j,3]=d[2,1]
              mat[j,4]=d[3,1]
              mat[j,5]=b[i,1]
              mat[j,6]=b[i,2]
              mat[j,7]=b[i,3]
              mat[j,8]=n;
              j=j+1;} 
            n=0;}                 


               }
          }
j=j+1;  
    }
write.csv(mat,"Count.csv", append = TRUE,row.names = FALSE)
```

Any help why that error message? Maybe I am ignoring something?

data are from a weather stations, therefore will have the following structure:

YY    MM DD Srad Tmax Tmin (Rain)
1980  1   1  3    2   -3

and goes on until Dec 31 2011

The expected output should be a csv file with the first Col the file name (each row would be a file), the second Col the Year when the first NA is encountered, the third Col the Month, the forth Col the Day when the the NA are found, the Fifth, sixth and seventh Cols the Ending years, Mm, and Dd when NA is last. The last col is the total number of NA for that time frame
Therefore for one file (e.g. File1.txt) there could 3 days of missing data from 1981-1-13 to  1981-2-1 and I will have in the last col the number of NA for this period. 
For the same file I might have another NA period later on (e.g. in 1997) and therefore on the third row I will have again Filename, period of starting and ending time frame and how many NAs. 
I hope this is not too confusing...

Comment: can you add a *small* snippet of data from an example test file and give your expected output?

Comment: data are from a weather stations, therefore will have the following structure:

YY MM DD Srad Tmax Tmin (Rain)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is ever "==" or "!=" to NA. Use `is.na()` or `!is.na()` instead. So the logical tests would be:

```
if ( is.na( b[i,5]) && ( b[i,1]>1980 ) )

if( !is.na(b[i+1,5]) || (i==(length(b[,1])-1)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much DWin, that is the problem of being still amateur with R. I am learning it day by day and I still made silly mistakes here and there I guess. 
This is really helpful!! thank a lot!

Comment: Again, thanks a lot! that works!! I see the point now! I was trying to do somewthing that logically had no sense. The reason was that before I had -99.9 instead of NAs when I replaced NAs I did not think thoroughly about that ! Thank you again!

Comment: @david Can you check this answer off so you get credit for response and Dwin gets credit for the answer?